# table-hover が効かない

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container" style="padding:20px 0">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
     <thead>
          <tr><th>foo</th><th>bar</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr><td>foo1</td><td>bar1</td></tr>
          <tr class=“warning"><td>foo2</td><td>bar2</td></tr>
          <tr><td>foo3</td><td>bar3</td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

table-hoverがなぜかききません。どうしてでしょうか？

Comment: ダブルクォーテーションが全角になってるのが原因ではないでしょうか

Comment: 全て半角に書き直しましたが、直りませんでした……

Comment: table-stripedとかtable-borderedは有効になっているのでしょうか？あと、bootstrapのバージョン、ご利用のブラウザの種類やバージョン等の情報を掲載すると、回答者の参考になると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考情報ですが、以下のコードでtable-hoverは有効になりました（Bootstrap v3.3.2、Safari Version 8.0.3で検証）。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="padding:20px 0">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>foo</th><th>bar</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>foo1</td><td>bar1</td></tr>
                <tr class="warning"><td>foo2</td><td>bar2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>foo3</td><td>bar3</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: もうしわけありません！！　こちらの手違いで、元のコードと掲載したコードがちょっと違っていました……。
tomute 様のコードが動いたので、イヤハヤ……オカシイゾ……と想い想い、眼をカッと見開いて、コードをイチから凝然（ジッ）と見ていると……抜けているではありませんか……</thead>が……ナァーンテコッタイ……ハッハッハ……。

Comment: @住みたい街１位西日暮里 解決出来たようで何よりです。本質問がクローズしている事を他のユーザに分かりやすくするために、本回答を承認するか、自身で解決策を回答してそれを承認して頂ければと思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer